# How to separate 2 Close[1]?

Tags: mql4

[image]
Code :

```
if ((Close[2] > Open[2]) && (Close[1] < Open[1])}
{
      if(High[2] > iHigh(NULL, 0, iHighest(NULL,0,MODE_HIGH,50,2))) {
            draw_purple_horizontal_line(High[2]); 
      }
}
if ((Close[1] > Open[1])&&(Close[1] > purple_horizontal_line)) { 
     openSellTrade(); 
}
```

Fail to open sell trade, because system looks at Old Close[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKE7q.png) which is not close above purple horizontal line yet. How to make system look for new Close[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKE7q.png)?

Comment: What is the code of `openSellTrade()`? maybe you have a mistake there, but you havent provided that piece of code, so your questions is not MCVE to go further. Also please explain how you store `purple_horizontal_line` and what do you do with `draw_purple_line(double value)`

Comment: Question is not very clear, but `Close[1]` is always the closed price of the last candle(which is candle that is previous to the currently opened one).

Do you want to open a sell when a candle closes above the purple line?